# What is motivation behind the fact that printing R vectors take equal (maximum one) amount of lines for each element?

Tags: r

The vector `x` has a large string at index 2, while a small string at index 1. When we do a print, even the entry at index 1 takes two lines. In other words, the element at index 2 is printed after leaving an empty line. When we run a command using `system` using `intern` arg, there may be outputs of varying length, and then output is clumsy, as maximum no of lines are used for each element of the vector

```
x = c("11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111")
x = c("2", x)
x

#Output
[1] "2"
                                                                                                                                              
[2] "11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

Comment: Are you looking for `cat(x)`?

Comment: I think the short answer is "it is how it is programmed". The same is the case for vectors like `c(3, 34, 3444, 3)`. The print method simply adds whitespace to give each element an equal width, and to ease reading in most common cases.

Comment: @Ben, probably something like `cat(x, sep = "\n")` ! @Oliver, But what was the motivation behind "programming" so !

Comment: I am inclined to believe the motivation is to ease readability. It is likely easier to read `[1]  3    34  3443    3` than reading it without whitespaces. In extreme cases (like yours) this is somewhat detrimental, but in these cases we likely don't often care to see the output in console printed format. Otherwise `cat` is an option. You could send a mail to the `r-devel` mailing list and see if someone in the core team has the specific answer. As it is not I think this would spur opinion based answers, as it is asking about motivation and not a specific programming problem.

Comment: That'a a fair point, Oliver. But what if a vector contains some large numbers, and some small numbers, but we will take more space to print ! Same way for strings. Why could printing with some delimiters, like a comma or space etc, not suffice ? I am sure R mailing list will provide more points ..

Comment: On thinking more, I realize that you are correct as sometimes delimiters may not always be as great ! Perhaps a space delimiter would be equivalent for a vector of numbers of same digits !

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when printing vectors in R, all elements are padded to have same width (with some cutoff for very long strings:

```
> x <- c('dfsdf', 'sdfosdjfojdvjsdpvjpsdjvsdpvpsdv', 'ldsvspd;pdv;pmsd;vm', 'vsvpsdvpsdvpsdmv', 'sdvnspdvnpsdpvmsdmvpsmdpvmsd', 'sdvpo')
> x
[1] "dfsdf"                           "sdfosdjfojdvjsdpvjpsdjvsdpvpsdv" "ldsvspd;pdv;pmsd;vm"            
[4] "vsvpsdvpsdvpsdmv"                "sdvnspdvnpsdpvmsdmvpsmdpvmsd"    "sdvpo"
```

This makes it in my opinion easier to read and trace multiple elements in larger vectors,
as all columns have the same number of elements (save perhaps for the last row).

Comment: I am not sure why StackOverflow has marked this question `opinion based`. Are motivations behind output `opinions` ? No they are choices made for a reason. If we don't know motivations, how will we know principles of a language. @StackOverflow, I am sorry, I feel disappointed !